# QEMU Clipboard Sharing on MacOS Host and Linux Guest

Tags: macos, copy-paste, virtualization, kvm

I have QEMU running successfully on **macOS Monterey 12.0.1**
I'm running a **ParrotOS** VM, and everything is working except that the clipboard is not shared between the host and guest.

I have installed `spice-vdagent` in the guest OS but that has not helped.

Here is the QEMU command I'm using to start the guest OS:

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 8G \
    -vga virtio \
    -display default,show-cursor=on \
    -usb \
    -device usb-tablet \
    -machine type=q35,accel=hvf \
    -drive file=parrot-2021.11.qcow2,if=virtio
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile qemu with SPICE extensions?  If not, there's no way to address the spice-vdagent from the QEMU side.  The default build of qemu-system-x86_64 does not have SPICE enabled.

Comment: How would one confirm whether QEMU is compiled with SPICE extensions? It appears that QEMU is using SPICE here, but clipboard is still a no-go.